# jQuery puff effect to return back the Div after the effect has been applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `jQuery puff effect` and I need to know how I can return the Div back onto the page once it has been puffed away!

Currently the code will make the Div disappear (basically it makes it puff away totally).

How can I make it not to puff the Div away totally ?

And how can I make it in a way so it will reappear the Div after the it has puffed it away?

This is the simple code I am using at the moment:

```
<script>
  $( '#myButton' ).click(function() {
     $( "#myDiv" ).effect( "puff", "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just toggle it again or use toggle as described in [DOCS](http://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/):

```
$( "#myDiv" ).toggle( "puff" );
```

If you want to change opacity to 50% than return all back to not transparent:

```
// 50% opacity
$("#myDiv").animate({'opacity': 0.5});
//return to normal
$("#myDiv").animate({'opacity': 1});
```

**EDIT:**

You need something like that [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NYzGs/1/)

If you are interested, the code of puff is:

```
$.effects.effect.puff = function( o, done ) {
    var elem = $( this ),
        mode = $.effects.setMode( elem, o.mode || "hide" ),
        hide = mode === "hide",
        percent = parseInt( o.percent, 10 ) || 150,
        factor = percent / 100,
        original = {
            height: elem.height(),
            width: elem.width(),
            outerHeight: elem.outerHeight(),
            outerWidth: elem.outerWidth()
        };

    $.extend( o, {
        effect: "scale",
        queue: false,
        fade: true,
        mode: mode,
        complete: done,
        percent: hide ? percent : 100,
        from: hide ?
            original :
            {
                height: original.height * factor,
                width: original.width * factor,
                outerHeight: original.outerHeight * factor,
                outerWidth: original.outerWidth * factor
            }
    });

    elem.effect( o );
};
```

You can change it to not hide the element, but i couldn't do that fast now.

Comment: is there anyway, to stop it from disappearing? lets say keep the opacity to 50% and then toggle it back?

Comment: no, what i mean was while the puff effect is being applied to the Div, is there any way to stop it to disappear totally as the puff effect makes it disappear and  `$( "#myDiv" ).toggle( "puff" );` makes it reappear. i hope i've explained it better now.

Comment: This code works almost exactly as i want but it will disappear totally and then reappear. I need to know how i can stop it from disappearing totally: `<script>
$( '#myButton' ).click(function() {
$( "#myDiv" ).effect( "puff", "slow" );
$( "#myDiv" ).toggle( "puff" );

});
</script>`

Comment: Puff sets display: none; You have to write your own puff that will animate width, height and opacity without hiding element.

Answer (score 0):

puff effect just hides you element, it sets `style="display: none;"`,
so you need just to show it back , you could use something like

```
$( "#myDiv" ).show( "slow" );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dDQZB/4/)

Answer (score 0):

use `toggle`

```
$('#tgBtn').toggle(function () {
    $('#toggledDiv').animate({'opacity': 1}, function(){ 
        $('#toggledDiv').hide('puff', 750); 
    });
}, function () {
    $('#toggledDiv').show('puff', 750, function(){ 
        $('#toggledDiv').animate({'opacity': 0.4}); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7FcA/5/